# npm install hangs in NodeSource example "Dockerizing your Node.js Applications"

Tags: node.js

Working through the very simple example in "[Dockerizing your Node.js Applications](https://nodesource.com/blog/dockerizing-your-nodejs-applications)" I get failures in the docker build step.

https://nodesource.com/blog/dockerizing-your-nodejs-applications

```
steve@steve-docker:~/projects/docker-tutorial$ docker build -t "myapp" .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 54.27 kB
Step 0 : FROM nodesource/node:4.0
4.0: Pulling from nodesource/node
7a42f1433a16: Already exists 
3d88cbf54477: Already exists 
f7de320a63d8: Already exists 
25ca017f7153: Already exists 
96682a971c4a: Already exists 
51b426f992a7: Already exists 
7c37012fed92: Already exists 
fd06eadac973: Already exists 
9763c03a384a: Already exists 
e4dca69ac79f: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:e0f4a2cef10482abf99a3dda475db22b9f1b3e0441ff5f4c40aa58820cfcaec9
Status: Downloaded newer image for nodesource/node:4.0
 ---> e4dca69ac79f
Step 1 : ADD package.json package.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cf6b38206c03
Step 2 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in fc2c50798256
npm WARN package.json docker-tutorial@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json docker-tutorial@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json docker-tutorial@1.0.0 No README data
```

The already exists are no doubt as I ran it beforehand

I don't know enough yet about docker to be able to debug within the context that docker build is running but npm install works fine in the host context (at command prompt). My guess is something is wrong with the nodesource/node image

I'm running Ubuntu 15.0 x64 in VirtualBox on Windows 10.

Comment: Do you see a Step 3 for the `ADD . .` statement? Those are just warnings because the [package.json](https://github.com/nodesource/docker-tutorial/blob/master/package.json) file doesn't have a description or repo. It should still work.

Comment: Hey Steve, could you please post your Dockerfile here?

Comment: FROM nodesource/node:4.0

    ADD package.json package.json
    RUN npm install
    ADD . .

    CMD [“node”,”app.js”]

Comment: Hello Steve, our blog post had an issue with the quotes... try using the new one posted https://nodesource.com/blog/dockerizing-your-nodejs-applications#dockerizing-the-app or change quotes to normal ones like ["node", "app.js"]

Comment: I just cut n pasted from your website.

Comment: Yes, we found an issue and we updated blog post just right now :)

Comment: Hmm - still hangs after those 3 warnings. And yes, I did refresh my browser.

Comment: but you seem to have discovered a case for this  - https://github.com/reinderien/mimic :D

Comment: OK so I removed .git and README.md and everything after the npm install in the Docker file and it still hangs! The package.json is OK as I can "npm install" on the command line. I'll have to assume my docker config is barfed.

Answer (score 1):

Run npm install directly by navigating to the project root folder.
Now run the docker build again - now it will not hang.
The reason could be docker unable to create node_modules folder when we run the build command or could be we have to pass permission while running build command

Answer (score 0):

please follow these steps:

- Install Docker using this guide https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/
- Clone the repository: git clone https://github.com/edsadr/docker-tutorial.git
- Create the Dockerfile inside the new directory, here is the content:

`FROM nodesource/node:4.0
 ADD package.json package.json
 RUN npm install
 ADD . .
 CMD ["node","app.js"]`

- Execute `sudo docker build -t "myapp" .`
- Execute `sudo docker run -it "myapp"`

and you should see something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - you just document what I did do :) 
I also added the docker group so the sudos are not needed. I just tried with sudo but makes no difference.

I will tear it all down and do it again when I get some time

Comment: Sorry to hear that Steve,tried this in Mac first and works without problem, same in 2 Ubuntu VM and everything just works ... perhaps is your Docker installation?

Comment: I certainly sounds like it's just me :( I'll post an updated after a clean install of everything.